# Jenkins build output set as current build description

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I want to set current build description in my jenkins job from `#bash` output

Jenkins build output set  as current build description

For example to set revision and branch from string and choice parameters I do it like this:

```
   parameters {
       string(defaultValue: "", description: '11.00', name: 'REVISION')
       choice(name: 'BRANCH', choices: 'trunk\nupdate', description: 'Branch')
   }

   stage('Set build') {
      steps {
         script {
             // Set build parameters
             currentBuild.description = "$REVISION $BRANCH"
         }
      }
   }
```

Let's say that I want get my diskspace % `#bash` execution and put it in the description...

```
   stage('bash') {
      steps {
         script {
         sh '''
            DISK_SIZE="$(df -h --output='pcent' /mnt | grep -v "Use%")
         }
        currentBuild.description = "$DISK_SIZE"
      }
   }
```

I want in the build description for example to put my disk%. In this case I expect to in the description `%30`

Or to put some other staff that are generated from current build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell your sh command to return its stdout using the `returnStdout` option.

```
myOutput = sh(script: '$(df -h --output='pcent' /mnt | grep -v "Use%")', returnStdout: true)

currentBuild.description = myOutput
```